# Template friend function instantiation

Tags: c++, function, templates, friend, friend-function

Why do I get a linker error for the following?

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A {
public:
    class B;
};

template<typename T, typename U>
class A<T, U>::B {
    friend bool operator==(const B& b1, const B& b2);
};

template<typename T, typename U>
bool operator==(const typename A<T, U>::B& b1, const typename A<T, U>::B& b2) {
    return true;
}

int main() {
    A<char, int>::B b1;
    A<char, int>::B b2;

    if (b1 == b2) {
        return 0;
    } else {
        return 1;
    }
}
```

The error I get is:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "operator==(A<char, int>::B const&, A<char, int>::B const&)", referenced from:
      _main in test-qSCyyF.o
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you're calling it and it has no definition!

This

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A<T, U>::B {
    friend bool operator==(const B& b1, const B& b2);
};
```

is a declaration of a *non-template* friend function of `A<T,U>::B` class.

It matches the call `(b1 == b2)` just as well as the template operator you define further down but it is preferred because it is a non-template.

GCC even gives a warning with `-Wnon-template-friend`

> warning: friend declaration 'bool operator==(const A::B&, const A::B&)' declares a non-template function [-Wnon-template-friend]
>   note: (if this is not what you intended, make sure the function template has already been declared and add <> after the function name here)

To fix, it provide the definition

```
template<typename T, typename U>
class A<T, U>::B {
    friend bool operator==(const B& b1, const B& b2) {
        return true;
    }
};
```

and get rid of the templated operator OR keep only the template one.

Comment: So… how do I fix it. =P

Comment: So I can't have a templated friend function that's defined outside of the class??

Comment: @fumoboy007 You usualy can, but in your case, with a nested non-template class? I don't think so, but I'm not sure :) I'd say you don't need it, but I don't know exactly what you're trying to achieve.

Comment: I modified my hierarchy so that I don't have that nested class anymore. Thanks for your help! =)